# Personalizing a class during execution that derives from an abstract class

Tags: c#

In below code, I am wondering how to identify which class is being executed in order to personalize it by applying a switch case or so. I tried by checking the Param T, however it didn't work for me.

Thanks in advance!

```
ExecuteCalculationsWith<RoofMaterialQuantityCalculator>();
ExecuteCalculationsWith<WallMaterialQuantityCalculator>();
ExecuteCalculationsWith<CurtainWallPanelsMaterialQuantityCalculator>();
ExecuteCalculationsWith<FloorMaterialQuantityCalculator>();

private void ExecuteCalculationsWith<T>() where T : MaterialQuantityCalculator, new()
{
    T calculator = new T();
    calculator.SetDocument(m_doc);
    calculator.CalculateMaterialQuantities();

    switch (typeof(T))
    {
        case RoofMaterialQuantityCalculator:
            calculator.InsertDataTableintoSQLTableusingSQLBulkCopy();
            break;
        case WallMaterialQuantityCalculator:
            calculator.InsertDataTableintoSQLTable_walls();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean like `typeof(T)`? but that already has a code smell: a generic method _should_ not need to know the specific type.

Comment: Yes, is there any way to know the typeof(T) @RenéVogt ?

Comment: yes, by [`typeof(T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/typeof)

Comment: I tried to do so, but didn't work @RenéVogt

Comment: all that code when a simple abstract main class could have done it or even better an interface with a method could have been used and no switch needed

Comment: Purpose of generics to have functions which doesn't care about actual implementation. Every time you check for actual type of generic mean - you did something wrong in your design.

Comment: With C#7 "Pattern matching" feature - you are able: `switch(calculator) { case RoofMaterialQuantityCalculator: // do something}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `typeof` operator. But you cannot `switch` on a `Type` instance.
<sub>(you *could* `switch` on the `Name` property of the `Type` instance, but I don't recommend that, because it's not reliable/maintenable/refactorable)</sub>

Try it like that:

```
private void ExecuteCalculationsWith<T>() where T : MaterialQuantityCalculator, new()
{
    T calculator = new T();
    calculator.SetDocument(m_doc);
    calculator.CalculateMaterialQuantities();       

    Type t = typeof(T);
    if (t == typeof(RoofMaterialQuantityCalculator))
        calculator.InsertDataTableintoSQLTableusingSQLBulkCopy();
    else if (t == typeof(WallMaterialQuantityCalculator))
        calculator.InsertDataTableintoSQLTable_walls();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be a better solution if `MaterialQuantityCalculator` class had an `abstract` method like `InsertDataTableIntoSqlTable()` and then each derived calculator implemented it so that your generic method would look like this:

```cs
private void ExecuteCalculationsWith<T>()
    where T : MaterialQuantityCalculator, new()
{
    T calculator = new T();
    calculator.SetDocument(m_doc);
    calculator.CalculateMaterialQuantities();
    calculator.InsertDataTableIntoSqlTable();
}

public abstract class MaterialQuantityCalculator
{
    public abstract void InsertDataTableIntoSqlTable();

    // rest is omitted for clarity
}

public class RoofMaterialQuantityCalculator : MaterialQuantityCalculator
{
    public override void InsertDataTableIntoSqlTable()
    {
        // Content of InsertDataTableintoSQLTableusingSQLBulkCopy() method comes here
    }

    // rest is omitted for clarity
}

public class WallMaterialQuantityCalculator : MaterialQuantityCalculator
{
    public override void InsertDataTableIntoSqlTable()
    {
        // Content of InsertDataTableintoSQLTable_walls() method comes here
    }

    // rest is omitted for clarity
}
```

Comment: `ExecuteCalculationsWith` should only be a method in `MaterialQuantityCalculator`